# FabricJS support for SVG viewBox element?

Tags: canvas, svg, viewbox, fabricjs

Does fabricJS support SVG viewBox element so that it will render only that on canvas? That way, zooming of the entire screen could be implemented easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, FabricJS is Canvas-based and Canvas and SVG are two very different realms.

FabricJS can *parse* SVG paths and draw them onto a canvas, but thats it.

Specifically, the SVG elements that FabricJS can parse and draw to a canvas are: path, circle, polygon, polyline, ellipse, rect, line, and image.

Comment: So rendered SVG from fabric would have viewBox dimensions the same as canvas dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

**Going the other way works**

I'm dealing with a related problem - rendering only part of the canvas into an SVG. I'm using the viewBox to ensure that users see only the interesting parts of the canvas.

[JSDoc for toSVG](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html)